# Hello World MVC JAVA (404)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

При переходе по ссылке у меня не находит hello и выходит ошибка

> HTTP Status 404 - /MVC/hello
>   type Status report
>   message /MVC/hello
>   description The requested resource is not available.

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="hello">Hello world</a>

</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>${message}</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

ControllerMain.java

```
package edu.spring.java.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class ControllerMain {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String helloWorld (ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!!!!");
        return "hello";
    }


}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
        xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
  <display-name> Lesson</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/lib/lessonmvc-servlet.xml</param-value>

 </context-param>



 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>





</web-app>
```

lessonmvc-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>




    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.spring" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>

    </bean>
</beans>
```

Вроде всё верно, но почему он не находит hello, не понятно (((

update:
Не правильно разместил web.xml. Разместил в lib, переместил в WEB-INF
теперь почему то не видит Dispatcher спринга, хотя всё подключено

> INFO: Marking servlet HelloWeb as unavailable янв 12, 2016 6:43:04 PM
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup SEVERE: Servlet
>
> /MVC threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: А как вы деплоите своё приложение?

Comment: Запускаю через eclipse в tomcat

Comment: хватит использовать уже xml

Comment: Попробуйте следовать инструкции отсюда: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23766404/1646082

Comment: Помести библиотеки spring'а в `WEB-INF/lib`. А вообще советую изучить maven или что-то подобное.

Comment: пробовал мавеном, так же всё было, попробовал по ссылке перетащить всё в web-inf/lib начались проблемы с xml конфигурацией. Щас задумался вообще переписать без xml с использованием JavaConfig

Comment: Это не решит проблему с classpath.